# Layout a binary search tree

Tags: ocaml

This is the problem 65 in [OCaml 99](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html)

> Given a binary search and layout it like this:

[image]

---

The y axis of a node is easy as it is just the level number, starting from 1.

The x asix of a node is bit more complicated, but through observation, assuming the height of the whole tree is `h`, then the x of a node is the max size of the left child as if it is a full tree, i.e., `x = 2 ^ (h-y)-1`

However, there is a special case where the x of the left most node is always **1** that we need to handle.

Here is my code:

```
type 'a btree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree

type 'a pos_binary_tree =
  | E (* represents the empty tree *)
  | N of 'a * int * int * 'a pos_binary_tree * 'a pos_binary_tree

let rec height = function
  | Empty -> 0
  | Node (_,l,r) -> 1 + max (height l) (height r)

let get_fullsize h level = (2. ** (Float.of_int (h+1-level)) |> Int.of_float) - 1

let layout_btree2_correct t = 
  let h = height t in
  let rec lay off y = function
    | Empty -> get_fullsize h y, E
    | Node (w, Empty, r) when off = 0 ->
      let wtr, newr = lay 1 (y+1) r in
      1+wtr, N (w, 1, y+1, E, newr)
    | Node (w, l, r) ->
      let wt1, newl = lay off (y+1) l in
      let wt2, newr = lay (off+wt1+1) (y+1) r in
      wt1+wt2+1, N (w, off+wt1+1, y, newl, newr)
  in 
  lay 0 1 t |> snd
```

---

What I do are:

1. get the height of the whole tree
2. always return back the full width that it might occupy
3. x should be the left node width + 1
4. For the special case of the left most node, it returns 1 + width of right as the width

In my way, I have to travel the tree one time first to get the height. Anyone can suggest better implementation, for example, just travel the tree once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for different algorithms to search the tree? Or different ways to implement that algorithm?

The Trees and Tree Algorithms section may be helpful to you. http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html